# ng-checked Radio Button not setting ng-model value in AngularJS on page load

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angular-ng-if, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-checked

I am learning angularJS and was trying to use `ng-model`, `ng-checked` and `ng-if` together for radio buttons

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular JS Radio Button Test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" ng-model="selectedGender" ng-checked="true"/>M<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" ng-model="selectedGender" />F<br />
    <div ng-if="selectedGender == 'M'">
        Male
    </div>
    <div ng-if="selectedGender == 'F'">
        Female
    </div>

</body>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>    
</html>
```

Now, on the initial page load, the "M" radio button is checked, but still the `<div ng-if="selectedGender == 'M'">` div does not show, unless I click on it again, after which it works.

What causes this issue, and how can it be fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialise in **"ng-init"** as below.

```
<body ng-app="" ng-init="selectedGender = 'M'">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" ng-model="selectedGender" ng-checked="true"/>M<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" ng-model="selectedGender" />F<br />
    <div ng-if="selectedGender == 'M'">
        Male
    </div>
    <div ng-if="selectedGender == 'F'">
        Female
    </div>

</body>
```

Working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/E7GIepCD8urP8SoiReWG?p=preview).

Comment: just an FYI, after adding that `ng-init`, I did  not need to use that `ng-checked` directive.

Comment: Yep..,true.Thanks.. @AyushGupta

Answer (score 2):

`ng-checked` Doesn't set value of `ng-model`

It will only help you to check or uncheck value based on scope value. By using ng-check directive you don't need to use `{{}}` interpolation, you can use scope values for forming an expression in it.

[**From docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

> **Note** that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

You should set ng-model value on intial load inside a controller

```
 $scope.selectedGender = 'M'
```

Comment: What do you mean? Don't make sense.

Comment: I mean the angular "feature" of `ng-checked` not setting `ng-model` is a bit "buggy".

Comment: No not at all.. its working as expected.. unless you are not setting a value of `ng-model`, it should not change its view.. I would say don't use `ng-checked` it lead to confusion.